# Table-column addressing in Python

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Often I select data from a SQLite database into a list of dictionaries using something like:

```
conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = conn.cursor()
selection = c.execute('select * from myTable')
dataset = selection.fetchall()
dataset1 = [dict(row) for row in dataset]
```

However, given my database background (Foxpro, SQL-server, etc.) I am more used to using table.column format, which I can get using:

```
dataset2 = [RowObj(row) for row in dataset]
```

where

```
class RowObj(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]
```

Question - What is preferable for column value addressing, table['column'] or table.column?  In my opinion the latter looks neater.  Is it just a matter of personal preference, or are there pros+cons of each approach?

I also need to bear-in mind that one day the database might be changed from SQLite to something line mySQL, so I want minimum code changes if/when that happens.

I don't want to use an ORM package like SQLObject or SQLAlchemy at this stage -  not until I am convinced they will benefit my applications.

Regards,
Alan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fought the `row['column']` syntax for a while, but in the end I prefer it.  It has two distinct advantages:

1. `row['class']` is correct syntax, but `row.class` is not; keywords cannot *directly* be used as property names.
2. And, more generally, if you ever craft a query whose column names are not valid property names (the above case included) the dictionary-style syntax will allow you to address that column.  `row.COUNT(*)` is obviously not valid syntax, but `row['COUNT(*)']` is, etc.  (Yes, you could use `AS` in the query to alias, and that's fine of course.  Still, it's a valid concern.)

Having said that, your `RowObj` class of course supports both means of addressing the columns.  I'd still prefer consistency though, and if you have a `class` column, it's going to look weird if you address it differently: `row.widget, row.dingus, row['class']`.  (One of these things is not like the other...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @cdhowie.  You put a good case for dictionary-keyword addressing.  Regards.